# C# - How to find out which permission an app domain needs?

Tags: c#, python, sandbox, appdomain, python.net

I have a sandbox application which runs untrusted code in a separate domain with restricted permissions. It's done like this example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046(v=vs.110).aspx.

As my untrusted code i have a Python.Net application that imports some modules from .py files and runs them. Everything works fine when permission set for the new domain is set like this:

```
PermissionSet permSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
```

However i need to grant it as few permissions as possible. I tried adding various permissions, but it still says that its unable to access the method from unsafe code that it's supposed to run.

```
PermissionSet permSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
permSet.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
permSet.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));

An unhandled exception of type 'System.MethodAccessException' occurred in SandboxWithPythonNet.exe
```

How do i check which permission i need to grant for it to run correctly?

EDIT1:
It seems that adding:

```
permSet.AddPermission(new ReflectionPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
permSet.AddPermission(new PrincipalPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
```

and setting

```
NewDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(System.Security.Principal.PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
```

allowed me at least to get to the untrusted code.
However now i'm unable to run Python.Runtime.Runtime.Initialize() because it is transparent. Error says that For methods to be allowed to run native code they have to be SecurityCritical or SecuritySafeCritical.

Is there a way of changing Python.Net's methods to SecurityCritical?

Comment: Here is an open issue for this: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/213

Comment: it is not possible to run pythonnet under SecurityCritical, because of usage of GCHandle.Free and AppDomain cannot be used for running untrusted code anyway.